# MULTER - req.files.filename returns undefined

Tags: node.js, multer

I try to get files.filename (multer multifile).

I upload 2 files ( 1 image and 1 video) upload is good. 
req.files.image and req.files.video have good values

```
console.log(req.files['image']);
console.log(req.files.video);
```

Values are good :

```
[ { fieldname: 'image',
    originalname: 'TEST-CAMPVIDEO1',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: '/media',
    filename: 'TEST-CAMPVIDEO11558696888750.jpg',
    path: '\\media\\TEST-CAMPVIDEO11558696888750.jpg',
    size: 10271 } ]
[ { fieldname: 'video',
    originalname: 'TEST-CAMPVIDEO1',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'video/mp4',
    destination: '/media',
    filename: 'TEST-CAMPVIDEO11558696888756.mp4',
    path: '\\media\\TEST-CAMPVIDEO11558696888756.mp4',
    size: 15535191 } ]
```

In node.js

but when i tried to get filename :

```
console.log(req.files['image']['filename']);
console.log(req.files.video.filename);
```

It returns undefined

Someone have an answer ???

Thanks friends :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the result of `req.files['image']` is an array. So you should, in this case, select the first and only item in it like this: `req.files['image'][0].filename` and it should work.

The array does only contain objects, not the filename property. The first object in the array does have the filename property

Answer (score 0):

Try it will be work

```
let filesArray = [];
req.files.forEach(element => {

    const file = {
        filename: element.filename
    }
    filesArray.push(file);
});
```

[multiple files uploads using multer](https://github.com/atul-coderial/products-listing)